Why Does Geometry Node Mesh Boolean Work for Some Objects But Not Others?
I am using Blender 4.1, and am trying to create an animation in which an object is only visible while it is in the interior of a cube (which will be made transparent).
To do this, I've created a very simple geometry node setup in which geometry from "Group Input" is combined with "Object Info" (a cube) in a Mesh Boolean node (set to "Intersect"). I am calling the cube the "Visibility Cube", because only those portions of the target mesh which are interior to the cube will be visible.
I have three objects: a sphere, a cone, and a text mesh object. I have created two versions of the node setup, one which I've named "Visibility Node - Works" and the other "Visibility Node - Doesn't Work". The only difference between the two of them is which of the two cubes is plugged in to the Mesh Boolean.

"Visibility Node - Doesn't Work": this node setup does what is expected for the cone object, but not for the text or the sphere.
"Visibility Node - Works": this node setup does what is expected for both the cone and the text, but also NOT the sphere.
If I swap the cubes in the "Visibility Node - Works" setup, the node setup continues to work for the cone, but NOT for the text!

This doesn't make any sense to me at all. I can't see any difference between the two cubes, other than their sizes and positions. And the sphere is just a mesh sphere, which hasn't had anything done to it other that application of a material. Same for the cone.

Is this a bug, or am I simply losing my mind?
Mesh Boolean Weirdness.blend

I could give you a working setup that would be very different from yours, so I'm just wondering if it has to be like you did it for some reason, with Geometry Nodes modifiers on almost all objects for whatever reason? Because the way I would do it (since you want to have one cube being the "visibility zone"), use a cube with Geometry Nodes where a collection of objects intersects with it...

i tried both - newest 4.3 alpha and 4.1 - both work in my test. Maybe download the newest 4.1 version?

Thank you so much for taking a look at this and your suggestion. I am really only starting to learn what I can do with geometry nodes. Your comment about having put geometry node modifiers on all objects made me realize that I had not put geometry node modifiers on either of the two cubes. Once I gave them each their own modifiers, the setup worked as I'd expected! Thank you again.
